# JS how to insert div after every 5 elem. with some class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to insert Ad div after every 5-th element with class 'art-item'  if not inserted yet.
I am trying  to do next:

```
function insertAfter(newNode, referenceNode) {
   referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}
function addAdvBlocks() {
    var items = document.getElementsByClassName('art-item');
    if(items.length<6){
       return;
    }
    var indx = 4;
    var slotDiv = document.createElement('div');
    slotDiv.id = '';
    slotDiv.className = 'item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 my-ad';

    while(indx<items.length){
       if(!items[indx].nextSibling.classList.contains('my-ad')){
           insertAfter(slotDiv,items[indx]);
        }
    indx+=6;
    }
}
```

But it's not working.
I tried to do it using Jquery, in this case, re-execute the function blocks are inserted in the wrong order.

```
var adBlock = '<div class="item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 my-ad"       style="width:300px;height: 250px"></div>';
$('.content-insertion > .art-item:nth-child(5n)').each(function (indx, elem)     {
    if (!$(elem).next().hasClass('my-ad')) {
        $(elem).after(adBlock);
    }
});
```

Pls, I need your help)

Comment: try to add `console.log(elem);` into the `$(.content....)` block. to figure out what DOM elements are touched.

Comment: It select rgiht elements. But the insertion of a new block does not always happen, though the paste function calls.

Comment: It inserst only after last processed element...

Comment: Your jquery logic works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/fv8fbcyr/

Comment: As i see jquery $('.art-item:nth-child(5n)') selector ignore ('.art-item') for second call of function. For second call it counts inserted blocks too... Why..

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments! I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution:

```
function addAdvBlocks() {
if ($('.item').length < 6)
    return;
var adBlock = '<div class="item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 my-ad" style="width:300px;height: 250px"></div>';
var outerIndx = 4;
$('.art-item').each(function (indx, elem) {
    if(indx == outerIndx){
        if (!$(elem).next().hasClass('my-ad')) {
            $(elem).after(adBlock);
        }
        outerIndx+=5;
    }
});
}
```

Now, on each call of this function `<div>` block will added (if not exists yet) after every 5-th element with class '.art-item'.
А теперь по-русски: функция вставляет блок после каждого пятого указанного, если он не был добавлен туда ранее.